# How can I get product list with its detail in rest API I'm on magento2

Tags: api, magento2, rest-api

I'm working on native mobile application and want to display product after customer selected a category. I am able to get list of the product by category in rest request but that list don't have much details about the product.

```
Request : http://localhost/magento2/index.php/rest/V1/categories/24/products
```

(**24 is category ID**)

```
Response : [{"sku":"WH01","position":1,"category_id":"24"},...]
```

Earlier in `Magento 1.9` product list was something like

```
{
2: {
entity_id: "2"
type_id: "simple"
sku: "Levis Bagpack"
description: "Bagpack"
short_description: "Bagpack"
meta_keyword: null
name: "Levis Bagpack"
meta_title: null
meta_description: null
regular_price_with_tax: 45
regular_price_without_tax: 45
final_price_with_tax: 45
final_price_without_tax: 45
is_saleable: true
image_url: "http://172.16.8.24:8080/magento/media/catalog/product/cache/0/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg"
}-
```

What should I do to get more info about product so I can show image and other things in mobile app ?

Comment: how to invoke SOAP API (example: Customer API)?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can try the GET /V1/products/:sku REST API to get all the details (https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/webapi.xml#l36)

The returned value will be representation of \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface (including the additional attributes)
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Api/Data/ProductInterface.php

Check \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::get which services the GET /V1/products/:sku REST API.

You can make multiple requests for all product SKUs.

OR

You can use the search API to fetch the entire list in a single request based on your criteria:

ex: http://localhost/magento2/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=sku&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=simple&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]=sku&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]=Simple2&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[current_page]=1&searchCriteria[page_size]=2

In this case products with SKUs - simple and Simple2 are being searched.

Comment: how to invoke SOAP API (example: Customer API)?

Comment: @ManojKumar http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/soap/soap-web-api-calls.html

Comment: we tried but i'm struck on this please see thread http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76569/class-magento-testframework-testcase-webapi-adapter-soap-not-found-in-magento

Comment: @airboss the URL of the image in the http://192.168.1.180/magento/index.php/rest/V1/products/SKU api is not a full url.. its something like this ' {
      "attribute_code": "small_image",
      "value": "/6/4/64275-152378-large.jpg"
    },' . ANy idea how to get the prefix for this URL?

Comment: use the storeConfigManager service and get the baseMediaUrl then add the path that you get from the image to come up with your full path.  You can also use secureMediaUrl for the secure base url.  - Link:  http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#!/storeStoreConfigManagerV1

Comment: How we can user searchCriteria[filter_groups][0] for filter sing category products.

Answer (score 2):

In addition (not as replacement) to the other answers, if after that you still are missing a piece of information, you can fill gaps by writing your own API functions: https://alankent.wordpress.com/2015/07/24/creating-a-new-rest-web-service-in-magento-2/

Comment: how to invoke SOAP API (example: Customer API)?

Answer (score 2):

```
define('BASEURL','http://localhost/magento20_0407/');

$apiUser = 'testUser'; 
$apiPass = 'admin123';
$apiUrl = BASEURL.'index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token';
/*
    Magento 2 REST API Authentication
*/
$data = array("username" => $apiUser, "password" => $apiPass);                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                       
try{
    $ch = curl_init($apiUrl); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
    );       
    $token = curl_exec($ch);
    $token = json_decode($token);
    if(isset($token->message)){
        echo $token->message;
    }else{
        $key = $token;
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
}


/*
    Get Product By SKU REST API Magento 2
    Use above key into header
*/
$headers = array("Authorization: Bearer $key"); 
//$requestUrl = BASEURL.'index.php/rest/V1/products/24-MB01';//24-MB01 is the sku.
//$requestUrl = BASEURL.'index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[page_size]=10';// get total 10 products
//$requestUrl = BASEURL.'index.php/rest/V1/categories/24/products';// 24 category id
$requestUrl = BASEURL.'index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria=';//get all products

$ch = curl_init();
try{
    $ch = curl_init($requestUrl); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $result = json_decode($result);

    if(isset($result->message)){
        echo $result->message;
    }else{
        print_r($result);
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

Similarly you can change $requestUrl and filter product list by category id and get product detail.

Please confirm whether it solves your problem or not. Else I'll post another solution.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @airboss said, we're working on our 'integration' style of APIs.  That's an API call that has extensible attributes add to it ( Catalog, Sales ).

In a few weeks you should be able to do a GET /V1/products/:sku REST API call and get everything related to that product ( if you're authorized as a customer you won't see the inventory object ).  For example if you call a sku that's a bundled product you'd get the simple product, an array of product options, an array of product links, media urls, and the inventory object*.  Same thing when you use the search ( we'll be calling it filter instead soon ) API.

-Chuck

Comment: the V1/products API does not include category_id parameter? ANy workaround for that ?