# Magento 2 rest api - How to post a product attribute?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I'm new in Magento 2, I want to add an attribute using REST api. Is it possible? I use the follow code for products:

```
<?php 
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);


$url = "http://mywebsite/";
$token_url = $url."rest/V1/integration/admin/token";
$product_url = $url. "rest/V1/products";
$username = "myUserName";
$password = "myPassword";



$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("username" => $username, "password" => $password);
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init($token_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
    );
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$adminToken=  json_decode($token);


$sampleProductData = array(
        'sku'               => 'config_product-small-red',
        'name'              => 'Simple Product ' . uniqid(),
        'visibility'        => 4, /*'catalog',*/
        'type_id'           => 'simple',
        'price'             => 99.95,
        'status'            => 1,
        'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
        'weight'            => 1,
        'custom_attributes' => array(
            array( 'attribute_code' => 'category_ids', 'value' => ["42","41","32"] ),
            array( 'attribute_code' => 'description', 'value' => 'Simple Description' ),
            array( 'attribute_code' => 'short_description', 'value' => 'Simple Short Description' ),
          array( 'attribute_code' => 'size', 'value' => '5' ), //5=small
          array( 'attribute_code' => 'color', 'value' => '8' ), //8-red
            ),
    'extension_attributes' => array(
        "stock_item"=>array(
            "qty"=>10,
            "is_in_stock"=>true,
        ),

    )
    );
$productData = json_encode(array('product' => $sampleProductData));
$setHaders = array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:Bearer '.$adminToken);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $product_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $productData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $setHaders);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($response);

?>
```

How can I do the same for product attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use **POST : `/V1/products/attributes`**

http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/ > **catalogProductAttributeRepositoryV1**

For example body JSON:

```
{
  "attribute": {
    "is_wysiwyg_enabled": true,
    "is_html_allowed_on_front": true,
    "used_for_sort_by": true,
    "is_filterable": true,
    "is_filterable_in_search": true,
    "is_used_in_grid": true,
    "is_visible_in_grid": true,
    "is_filterable_in_grid": true,
    "position": 0,
    "apply_to": [
      "string"
    ],
    "is_searchable": "string",
    "is_visible_in_advanced_search": "string",
    "is_comparable": "string",
    "is_used_for_promo_rules": "string",
    "is_visible_on_front": "string",
    "used_in_product_listing": "string",
    "is_visible": true,
    "scope": "string",
    "extension_attributes": {},
    "attribute_id": 0,
    "attribute_code": "string",
    "frontend_input": "string",
    "entity_type_id": "string",
    "is_required": true,
    "options": [
      {
        "label": "string",
        "value": "string",
        "sort_order": 0,
        "is_default": true,
        "store_labels": [
          {
            "store_id": 0,
            "label": "string"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "is_user_defined": true,
    "default_frontend_label": "string",
    "frontend_labels": [
      {
        "store_id": 0,
        "label": "string"
      }
    ],
    "note": "string",
    "backend_type": "string",
    "backend_model": "string",
    "source_model": "string",
    "default_value": "string",
    "is_unique": "string",
    "frontend_class": "string",
    "validation_rules": [
      {
        "key": "string",
        "value": "string"
      }
    ],
    "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "string",
        "value": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You also can read more here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/149927/33057

Comment: Thank you Khoa TruongDinh but 
1 - where I have to put the above json in my php code?
2 - what are the mandatory labels ?

Comment: Which Tool you use for testing API?

Comment: I am using postman for chrome but I execute the the above code from an remote server and working well. So I'm trying to customize the code in order to be able to add the attribute remotely.

Comment: So, you need a PHP data array?

Comment: Yes please ....

Comment: @MakisPapadopoulos you should take a look: https://gist.github.com/mrkhoa99/aa99372a86ba43eca4664f2123157518

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh, can you provide me what are the mandatory values to create product attribute? I have created a custom api here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257047/create-product-attribute-with-options-in-magento2-through-rest-api