# Product attribute create issue magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, installer

I am using below script to create product attribute with options.

```
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $setup = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface');
$eav_setup_factory = $obj->get('Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory');

    $setup->startSetup();
    $eavSetup = $eav_setup_factory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    // Product Attribute
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'customattribute',
        [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Custom Attribute Label',
            'backend' => '',
            'input' => 'select',
            'wysiwyg_enabled'   => false,
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'filterable' => true,
            'sort_order' => 3,
            'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'group' => 'custom attribute group',
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'option'     => [
            'values' => [
                0 => 'Small',
                1 => 'Medium',
                2 => 'Large',
            ]
        ],
        ]
    );
```

The options are not getting created with the above code. How can we create options?

The attribute is created once used the above code. Also, can we specify the attribute set to this code? by default, it is adding to the Default attribute set.

Can anybody help me with the above issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to create a installer file name **InstallData.php** in our custom module Setup folder

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup; 
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory; 
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        /**
         * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
         */
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,'yourcustomattribute_id');
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'yourcustomattribute_id',
            [
                'group' => 'Product Details',
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Your Custom Attribute Label',
                'input' => 'select',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => 'Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Options',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Now we create option source file class Options for custom attribute options list

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Config/Source/Options.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\OptionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class Options extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{


    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        /* your Attribute options list*/
        $this->_options = [
            ['label' => 'Select Options', 'value' => ''],
            ['label' => 'Option1', 'value' => '1'],
            ['label' => 'Option2', 'value' => '2'],
            ['label' => 'Option3', 'value' => '3'],
        ];
        return $this->_options;
    }

    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
            if ($option['value'] == $value) {
                return $option['label'];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getFlatColumns()
    {
        $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
        return [
            $attributeCode => [
                'unsigned' => false,
                'default' => null,
                'extra' => null,
                'type' => Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                'nullable' => true,
                'comment' => 'Custom Attribute Options  ' . $attributeCode . ' column',
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-how-to-create-product-custom-attribute-from-installer-in-custom-module/)

Comment: i mam reading option from json, how to parse it?
below is the json
"Attribute": "Test Attribute",
    "data_type" :"text",
      "OptionValues": {
        "Value": "Advanced Diploma"
     
  }

Comment: $json_decoded = $this->jsonHelper->jsonDecode($json_encoded); It will return array then you can read it.

Comment: , can we not create attribute with custom rest api? like this 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257047/create-product-attribute-with-options-in-magento2-through-rest-api

Comment: I will look it and give update soon.

Comment: after creating attribute , can we get the attribute_id?

Comment: Hi rohan, could u check the issue?