# Is possible to create REST API with Basic Auth?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I've created **REST API in Magento2 but everyone can use it**. How can I add basic auth to my API?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add: `<resource ref="anonymous" />`

For example:

*vendor/magento/module-search/etc/webapi.xml*

```
<route url="/V1/search" method="GET">
    <service class="Magento\Search\Api\SearchInterface" method="search"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

Comment: but how can i set login and password for this service?

Comment: Can you explain more details?

Comment: You should read more here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/149927/33057

Comment: When resource ref is set to anonymous, everyone can send request. I want to set Authorization type to "Basic Auth" which means that before send requst it is necessary to put login and password to request. 

[link]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: @Wojciech Ka have you found solution?